# Is this kata solution considered O(n)?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have the following solution to a kata:

```
def commonalities(array1, array2)
  in_common = false
    array1.each do |elem|
      if array2.include?(elem)
        in_common = true
        break
      end
    end
  puts in_common
end


##### Problem: Should find common elements in an array 

array1 = ['a','b','c','x']
array2 = ['z','y','i']
commonalities(array1, array2)
# return false
array1 = ['a','b','c','x']
array2 = ['z','y','x']
# return true
commonalities(array1, array2)
```

I'm relearning BigO notation and doing some job interview katas. From what I've learned so far, I would say that this implementation is O(n) notation which is considered "fair". Is this a correct assumption? I say that this is O(n) because I have one loop, the `.each`. The bigger the array gets the longer it would take. This to me implies a linear O. However, the `.include?` is throwing me off. I don't know how the internals of `.include?` works. Does it even matter? Am I indeed correct to say that this is O(n)? Confirmation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Easy answer: Benchmark it for various values of *N* and find out yourself.

Comment: There's some irregularities in the indentation here that implies structure that isn't there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. I understand now that its O(nm) and thus very slow. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Hint: `array1 & array2` yields overlapping elements. That method's fairly optimized, so use that as a target.

Comment: Please provide a link to the kata problem you are solving, or at least summarise the problem. It's annoying to be asked to read code without any explanation of the problem that is being addressed.

Comment: The problem is in the question. Find common elements in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal implementation of `.include?` does matter, because it's likely another `for` or `each` loop, so closer to O(*mn*).

If you knew that e.g. array1 was guaranteed to be a constant size, you could say that it's O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the other array. However, in this kind of problem, we generally assume that both arrays have variable length, so this implementation would be thought of as O(*mn*), or as O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) if the two lists are known to have the same length.

Comment: Rather than O(n²), I think it's more accurate to write O(mn), where *m* is the length of one array and *n* is the length of the other.

Comment: Since both arrays are different lengths, this is O(nm). It would be O(n^2) only if they had the same size.

Comment: Since big-O is an upper bound, and *n* is the size of the input unless otherwise specified, O(n²) is completely valid even if the arrays aren't assumed to be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that 'n' just describes the size of some input. In your example, you have two inputs `(array1, array2)`.

Looping over `array1` can be described as `O(n)` where n is the size of the array.

But what about `array2`? How does its size affect the runtime of your algorithm? It's an array, so running a contains operation is linear too.

What you're looking at is `O(nm)`.

Answer (score 0):

If arrays are not sorted it is proven that there is no algorithm that works faster than O(n log n).

For each element in array1 you check if it occurs in array2. So your computer must somehow know the answer.

Looking at .include? implementation you can easily see that it iterates through array2 and checks for the element.

```
       VALUE
       rb_ary_includes(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
       {
            long i;
            VALUE e;

             for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
             e = RARRAY_AREF(ary, i);
             if (rb_equal(e, item)) {
                  return Qtrue;
              }
         }
         return Qfalse;
        }
```

One call of that function is O(n) then. That is why the complexity of your algorithm is O(n^2)

(Well, O(nm) more correctly, where n is the length of array1 and m is the length of array2)